# Converting rdpmc_reference_cycles to 64-bit in MASM

Tags: windows, assembly, x86-64, masm, msr

I've been using the following code in assembly language to read performance-monitoring counters using the RDPMC instruction:

```
rdpmc_reference_cycles proc
    mov ecx, 1h
    shl ecx, 30
    add ecx, 2
    xor eax, eax
    xor edx, edx
    rdpmc
    ret
rdpmc_reference_cycles endp
```

This works fine for a 32-bit environment, but now I'm transitioning to a 64-bit system and I'm having trouble adapting the code. After the `rdpmc` instruction, the 32-bit value in eax contains the lower half of the result, and the 32-bit value in edx contains the upper half.

I need to combine these two 32-bit values to produce a 64-bit result. However, I'm not sure how to achieve this in MASM. I've tried a few approaches, but they didn't work as expected. Could anyone guide me on how to modify this code so that it produces a 64-bit result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [RDPMC](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/rdpmc) instruction only depends on the ECX register for an input (in the 64-bit environment the high dword of RCX is ignored). And the result is returned in EDX:EAX with the high dwords of RAX and RDX reset to zero.

Your code

> ```
> mov ecx, 1h
> shl ecx, 30
> add ecx, 2
> xor eax, eax
> xor edx, edx
> rdpmc
> ```

is convoluted because

- it uses 3 instructions to load ECX instead of the one `mov ecx, 40000002h` (equivalent to `mov ecx, (1<<30) + 2`).
- it clears both RAX and RDX for no good reason

So to read the counter and deliver the 64-bit result in the single RAX register, you can do:

```
mov   ecx, (1<<30) + 2
rdpmc                   ; -> EDX:EAX
shl   rdx, 32
or    rax, rdx
```

The `shl rdx, 32` shifts the contents of EDX into the high dword of RDX.
The `or rax, rdx` combines both dwords in RAX.
It is important to note that this `or` could only work well because the `shl` made the low dword of RDX zero, and because the `rdpmc` made the high dword of RAX zero.

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate the time everyone has taken to read and consider my question. I was struggling to adapt my 32-bit assembly code using the RDPMC instruction to a 64-bit environment, specifically in combining the 32-bit results from the EAX and EDX registers into a 64-bit result.

After some further research and trials, I've managed to find a solution that works. Here's the modified version of the code that successfully combines the results into a full 64-bit result

```
rdpmc_reference_cycles proc
    mov ecx, 1h
    shl ecx, 30
    add ecx, 2
    xor eax, eax
    xor edx, edx
    rdpmc
    shl rdx, 32          ; Shift the high 32 bits to their place
    or rax, rdx          ; Combine the high 32 bits (now in rdx) and low 32 bits (in eax)
    ret
rdpmc_reference_cycles endp
```

In this solution, I've shifted the higher 32 bits from EDX to their appropriate place in a 64-bit number (RDX). After this shift, I've combined (OR operation) the resulting RDX with the lower 32 bits from EAX. This way, I've been able to form a full 64-bit result in RAX.

I hope this solution can help others who might be facing a similar issue. I welcome any further insight or suggestions from the community. Thank you!